# Can I use templates to deploy kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

We are trying to use Kubernetes to deploy our application, currently, we have +30 microservices and we have a files mess.

we tried Kustomization to add a patch and create ConfigMaps depending on the overlay, and also merge some files. But we always need to create a lot of files, 1 for each deployment/service. And at the end when we want to update something, for example, replicas, is a bit painful.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
  selector:
    app: service1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service1
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: pyfarm-registry.local:5000/pyfarm/svclocation:dev
        name: service1
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: configName
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: local-registry
```

We have this file duplicated by +30 times, changing names, and env variables. But I am sure has to have something to parse these templates.

We already tried to implement Helm, but is not what we are finding.

Can we do for example 1 file with variables and generate the other 30 files, also we need different namespaces. Is it possible?

The only solution we found is using bash, but there are something more elegant?

Comment: I'm impressed that Helm is not what you are looking for...By the way, take a look at the [awesome-kubernetes](https://github.com/ramitsurana/awesome-kubernetes) list, it's a good point of start when searching for Kubernetes tools.

Comment: The reason is we are working with the condition of security is the first thing to have in mind. And we want to have some tool like OC process, simpler than Helm. The link you share is so useful, but I cannot find any solution for the problem exposed. Really appreciated your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As [Kustomization](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/05/29/introducing-kustomize-template-free-configuration-customization-for-kubernetes/) and [Helm template](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/) (as you mentiones security/privilige reasons) are not working for you, I don't think that you can do anything else.
Only things comes to my mind except BASH script are Tempalte Designers:

1) [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) which is template languate for Python. It is fast, widely used and secure with the optional sandboxed template execution environment.

2) [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) is a simple web template system with implementations available for ActionScript, C++ etc. It's call "logic-less" because there are no if statements, else clauses, or for loops.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it feels as if helm is perfectly suited to what you’re doing here. Helm’s superpowers are templating and release / change management.

In what way didn’t it work for you?

Comment: The reason is security concerns, and we want to be simple. In our main servers, we are using Openshift and I really like the idea of templates: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-parameters we want to find the way to do something similar with kubernetes.